# is there a way to make GET/POST data usable only once and cleared on refresh?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to make GET/Post data usable only once on first instance? I'm using GET data to check success of a comment and do some actions and display certain messages. But I don't want this actions to be repeatable on refresh of a browser. What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the user from resubmitting the request, even if they're deliberately trying to do so? Or do you just want to stop them from doing it accidentally? If the latter, then you can process the request and then redirect the user back to the same page but with the request removed.

Comment: @octern, this technique works most of the time, but in really important cases connection problems may lead to processing request twice.

Comment: @octern Actually both, but I'm more worried about accidental ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can add a unique token to the data and reject it on the server side if the token is already used.

Comment: What? An example of adding a unique token to POST/GET data? Or an example of checking on the server side?

Comment: Can you give me easy php example of both? I will search for tutorial, but easy condensed example would be nice...

Comment: 1) create a random token and include it in the page that will send the request. 2) save the token to a database table containing all the tokens you've generated, with a status field indicating that it hasn't been used. 3) When a form containing that token is submitted, check the table. If the token hasn't been used, process the form and then update the table to show that the token has been used.  If it has been used, reject the form.

Comment: I didn't want to involve database at all. Can I do it with cookies instead?

Comment: Well, to implement this, you have to have some kind of persistent storage. It can be database, it can be something like memcached, or any other store. you may limit the lifetime of the objects there by embedding timestamp and allowing for like 24 hours or so, but whatever you do, you need some storage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **GET** requests,

one way you can check for the request uri like

```
$is_new_request = true;

if(isset($_SESSION['req_uri']) && ($_SESSION['req_uri'] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    $is_new_request = false;
    //handle your duplicate requests
    //better to redirect
}

if($is_new_request){
    $_SESSION['req_uri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    //Handle your first and unique requests
}
```

For **POST** requests

The better solution is a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)